# Opening an Excel File Using an Applet and Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, applet, apache-poi

I have this code

```
try {
  url       = new URL("http://miprueba.co.nf/prueba.xls");
  input     = url.openStream();
  bookModel = new HSSFWorkbook(input);
} catch {
  ...
}
```

In the server, in the folder miprueba.co.nf, I have the "myapplet.jar" and "prueba.xls" together with a subdirectory "lib" with the "poi-3.9-2021203.jar"

This is the message that I get from the Console in the line of the code "bookModel = new..."

```
network: cache not found [URL: http://miprueba.co.nf/lib/poi-3.9-20121203.jar, versión: null]

network: Connectin http//miprueba.co.nf/lib/poi-3.9-20121203.jar con proxy=DIRECT

network: CleanupThread used 5 us

network: Downloading resource: http//miprueba.co.nf/lib/poi-3.9-20121203.jar
 Content-Lenght: 1.821.732
 Content-Encoding: null

network: Cache not found [URL: http//miprueba.co.nf/, versión: null]

network: Cache not found [URL: http//miprueba.co.nf/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.class, versión: null]

network: Connecting http//miprueba.co.nf/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.class con proxy=DIRECT
network: CleanupThread used 5 us

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook
 at applettest.Variables.<init>(Variables.java:50)
 at applettest.myApplet.jButton2ActionPerformed(myApplet.java:124)
....
....
....
```

Any help?
I want to be able to read a number from the excel file "prueba.xls".
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The key line is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook
```

You're missing the Apache POI jars from your runtime classpath. You should either fix it so that your app correctly loads it, or produce a single jar containing your code and all the dependencies. Either way, you need to have POI available at runtime if you want to use it!

Comment: I agree, but I have the Apache POI jars in the "lib" subdirectory. That is the "poi-3.9-20121203.jar" which it seems to be downloaded in the line

`network: Downloading resource: http//miprueba.co.nf/lib/poi-3.9-20121203.jar
 Content-Lenght: 1.821.732
 Content-Encoding: null`


I will try to produce a single jar.

Comment: There are a lot of apparent typos in that, eg `http//` and `Content-Lenght` - did you have to retype the messages, or could something be very broken in your setup?

Comment: Garavarr, the http typos I made it on purpouse, because my stackoverflow account doesn't allow me to publish more than 2 hyperlinks. This is way I change http:// to http//.
Even thought the syntaxis of the message might be wrong, the semantic si the right one.

Answer (score 0):

If think that the MIME type on the server side is incorrect for the .jar files.

If I look at the poi-3.9-20121203.jar that I downloaded from the POI website, I have 1,869,113 bytes. You logs says 1.821.732 bytes.

Another possibility is that you recompiled the library with Java 7 and the Applet runs with Java 6.

Here is for your *.htaccess*

> AddType application/java-archive .jar

Answer (score 0):

What i get from above is - you are trying to use third party jar in `applet` i.e. to read from `excel`. To make applet use third party jars, make them signed using `jarsigner`.

Sign your third party jar put them in `classpath`, it should work then.